# Inlining a function that manipulates data on heap

Tags: c++, multithreading, inline, compiler-optimization, heap-memory

I'm working on optimizing a code where most of the objects are allocated on heap.

What I'm trying to understand is: if/why the compiler might *not* inline a function call that potentially manipulates data on heap.

To make things more clear, suppose you have the following code:

```
class A
{
public: 
   void foo() // non-const function
   {
     // modify data
     i++;        
     ...
   }
private:    
  int i; 
  // can be anything here, including pointers      
};

int main()
{
  A a; // allocate something on stack
  auto ptr = std::make_unique<A>(); // allocate something on heap

  a.foo();  // case 1
  ptr->foo(); // case 2
  return 0;
}
```

Is it possible that `a.foo()` gets inlined while `ptr->foo()` does not?

My guess is that this might be related to the fact the compiler does not have any guarantee that data on heap won't be modified by another thread. However, I don't understand if/why it can have any impact on inlining.

Assume that there are no virtual functions

EDIT: I guess my question is partially theoretical. Suppose you are implementing a compiler, can you think of any legitimate reason why you won't optimize `ptr->foo()` while optimizing `a.foo()`?

Comment: Inlining is an implementation detail, that may improve or reduce performance. A compiler may choose to not inline code that it is capable of inlining, for whatever reasons it wants.

Comment: This question can only be answered in the context of a specific compiler with specific optimization settings on a specific architecture; and in most cases, the compiler's author may not be inclined to share those details.  If you really want to study optimizer decision-making, you could look at g++ source code for one example.  But look... Even when you would explicitly request inlining (a common practice once upon a time in C, if not so much today), the compiler was free to say "no".  There's a reason we leave optimization to the compilers.

Comment: Note that your assertion that `a` is allocated on "the stack" is also subject to the whim of the compiler. In your example I can imagine some compiler placing it entirely in registers

Comment: I guess my question is partially theoretical. Suppose you are implementing a compiler, can you think of any legitimate reason why you won't optimize `ptr->foo()` while optimizing `a.foo()`?

Comment: Use http://godbolt.org/ and check with a few compilers and different optimization settings.

Comment: Your question seems to have nothing to do with "the heap" (whatever that is) and more to do with accessing an object via dereference vs not.

Comment: `A a; // allocate something on stack` No. `auto ptr = std::make_unique<A>(); // allocate something on heap` No. Somebody has been teaching you fundamental misconceptions.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition are you saying that `a` memory layout might not be mapped to stack segment? you mean it can be stored in registers/cache?

Comment: Assuming you are seeing difference in performance for scenario 1 and 2, I would more readily attribute it to indirect access rather than inlining.

Comment: @SergeyA  good point. I want to understand if indirect access and inlining are correlated

Comment: @NarekSaribekyan, unlikely. However, you have the final arbiter - codegen.

Comment: @NarekSaribekyan: Of course. Or, it may not even exist at all, since you never did anything with its data. C++ is an abstraction that describes the semantics of a program, not a one-to-one mapping of machine code instructions. The sooner you stop assuming particular implementation details, the better off you'll be!

Comment: @BoundaryImposition, thanks for elaborating. The problem is I don't know the standard terminology for referring to semantics of case 1/case 2.

Comment: @NarekSaribekyan: Automatic/dynamic storage duration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My guess is that this might be related to the fact the compiler does not have any guarantee that data on heap won't be modified by another thread. However, I don't understand if/why it can have any impact on inlining.

That is not relevant. Inline function and "regular" function calls have the same effect on the heap.
The implementation, inline or not, is in the code segment anyway.

> Is it possible that a.foo() gets inlined while ptr->foo() does not?

Highly unlikely. Both of these calls will be probably inlined if the implementation is visible to the compiler and the compiler decide that it would be beneficial.
*I used "case 2" in my code numerous times and it was always inlined using g++.*

Although it is mostly implementation specific, there are no real limitation that restrict pointer function call compared to calling using an on stack object (beside the virtual functions which you already mentioned).

You should note that the produced inlined code might still be different. Case 2 will have to first determine the actual address which will have an impact on the performance, but it should be pretty much the same from there.

Comment: why? after all, `foo` is not virtual.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I'm interested in the case when there are no virtual functions.

Comment: Two comments to say "but I want to know about the non-virtual case", in spite of the fact that the answer does attempt to address the non-virtual case.  (That said, the answer is making assumptions about implementation-dependent behavior, so in a technical sense it's wrong.)

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger, I made that comment before it was edited.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger And I referred to virtual function before the question was edited :)

Comment: @LiranFunaro, l'll wait for some more answers before accepting this one.

Answer (score 1):

> if/why the compiler might not inline a function call that potentially manipulates data on heap.

The compiler is free to [inline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion) or *not* a function call (and might decide that after [devirtualization](http://hubicka.blogspot.fr/2014/01/devirtualization-in-c-part-1.html)). The inlining decision is the freedom of the compiler (so `inline` keyword, like `register`, is often ignored to make optimizing decisions). The compiler often would decide to inline (or not) every particular call (so every *occurrence* of the called function name).

> Suppose you are implementing a compiler, can you think of any legitimate reason why you won't optimize `ptr->foo()` while optimizing `a.foo()`?

This is really easy. Often, (among other criteria) the inlining is decided according to the depth of previously inlined nested function calls, or according the current size of the expanded internal representation. So it does happen that a particular occurrence of `ptr->foo()` would be inlined (e.g. because it occurs in a small function) but another occurrence of `a.foo()` won't be inlined.

Remember, inlining decisions is generally taken at each call site. And on some compilers, the thresholds used by the compiler may vary or can be tuned.

But **inlining does not always speed up execution time** (because of [CPU cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache) and [branch predictor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_predictor) issues, and many other mysteries....), and that is yet another reason why sometimes a compiler won't inline a particular call.

For [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler, read about [inline functions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Inline.html) and various [optimization options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options) (notice that `-finline-limit=100` and `-finline-limit=200` will give *different* inlining decisions; you could even play with different `--params` options; the [MILEPOST GCC](http://ctuning.org/wiki/index.php?title=CTools:MilepostGCC) project used machine learning techniques to tune these....).

Perhaps some compilers can more easily do devirtualization for stack allocated data (I really don't know, and compilers are making progress on such issues). This is probably the reason why (perhaps!) heap vs stack allocation could influence inlining decisions.

Comment: I think that the main issue is that calling the function via a pointer reference is irrelevant. The rest is just nice to know information.